# How to disable buttons in GTK3

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

Windows API has a function called `EnableWindow` that disables controls so user can't interact with them any more.

Is there an equivalent for GTK3 or GTK3++?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
gtk_widget_set_sensitive (widget, FALSE);
```

Note that if you need to check whether a widget is sensitive,  `gtk_widget_get_sensitive()` returns the value set with the above function and `gtk_widget_is_sensitive()` will tell you whether the widget *really* is sensitive -- this is affected by parent widgets sensitivity as well.

Answer (score 4):

For specific control, I think you can use "set_sensitive":

```
var button = new Gtk.Button.with_label("Hello");

button.set_sensitive(false); // true to enable the button
```

Comment: this works perfect in gnome shell extension prefs.js